# Retrive additional tag info in json response

Tags: brightcove

When i use get method on the below bright cove api to retrive video meta data, it generates json response with some fields.

```
"https://cms.api.brightcove.com/v1/accounts/510000340001/videos?sort=-updated_at&limit=1&offset=0"
```

How do we get additional tags which are not included, say for example 'category' field in the output json response?

I tried to append below in url and api does not detect.

```
?custom_field=category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the video has a value set for that field, it will be present in the `custom_fields` object as below. If the field is empty, it will not be included for that video.

```
{
  "name": "A video",
  ...
  "custom_fields": {
    "category": "something"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://apis.support.brightcove.com/cms/code-samples/cms-api-sample-video-sitemap-generator.html It is not a custom field, it is an tag that's not included as mentioned in the link. Is there any api call which would let me retreive the tags that are not included.

Comment: If your question now is "how do I get tags in the response", it's already in there in the `tags` property. If it's "how do I only get videos with tag x" it's `?query=tags:x` https://apis.support.brightcove.com/cms/searching/cms-and-playback-apis-video-search-v2.html